# mongoengine Document vs DynamicDocument accessing nested elements with dotted notation

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have following documents:

```
import mongoengine as mongo

class A(mongo.Document):
   a = mongo.DictField()

class B(mongo.DynamicDocument):
  b = mongo.DictField()


A(a=dict(a=1)).save()
B(b=dict(b=1)).save()
```

This works:

```
B.objects(**{'b.b':1})
```

This does not:

```
A.objects(**{'a.a':1})
InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "a.a""
```

I know, that I could use double underscores. But I just find dotted notation nicer.

Any idea why would Document and DynamicDocument behave differently ?

Thanks